# How to add a method inside the constructor class in PHP?

Tags: php, methods, dynamic

I have a `class A` which needs a new method if one of its arguments is set up to `true`.

**Class A**

```
Class A{

   private $is_new_method;  

   public function __construct( $is_new_method = false, $new_method_name = "" ){

        $this->is_new_method = $is_new_method;

        if( $this->is_new_method ){
           //TODO : add new method in this class based on $new_method_name 
        }      
   }

}
```

I saw [runkit_method_add](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php) but it needs (PECL runkit >= 0.7.0).

Notice: this function will be call inside a core of a framework like this :

```
$foo = new A();
$foo->myNewFunction();
```

So what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you just use [magic `__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) or [magic `__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jared Farrish !
I found my solution based on your recommandation.

```
Class A{

    private $is_new_method; 

    private $new_method; 

    public function __construct( $is_new_method = false, $new_method_name = "" ){

        $this->is_new_method = $is_new_method;

        if( $this->is_new_method ){
           $new_method = $this->make_my_new_method( $new_method_name ); 
        }      
   }

   private function make_my_new_method( $method_name ){
        $functionName  = "foo_" . $method_name;
        $$functionName = function ( $item ) {
            print_r( $item );
        }
        return $$functionName;
   }

   public function __call( $method, $args){
       if ( isset( $this->new_method ) ) {
           $func = $this->new_method;
           return call_user_func_array( $func, $args );
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = new Inflector([
    'foo' => function($val){echo sprintf('%s calls foo()', $val[0] ?? 'none!').PHP_EOL;},
    'bar' => function($val){echo sprintf('%s calls bar()', $val[0] ?? 'none!').PHP_EOL;},
    'baz' => function($val){echo sprintf('%s calls baz()', $val[0] ?? 'none!').PHP_EOL;},
]);

$a->foo('Ahnold');
$a->bar('Elvis');
$a->baz('Lerhman');
$a->theBreaks('Who');

class Inflector
{
    private $methods = [];

    public function __construct(array $methods)
    {
        $this->methods = $methods;

        //var_dump($this->methods);
    }

    public function __call(string $methodName, $params)
    {
        if (isset($this->methods[$methodName])) {
            $this->methods[$methodName]($params);
        }

        throw new InflectionDeceptionException();
    }

}

class InflectionDeceptionException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = "Say what?")
    {
        return parent::__construct($message);
    }

}
```

https://3v4l.org/kLdOp

Gives:

```
Ahnold calls foo()
Elvis calls bar()
Lerhman calls baz()
```

Comment: If I understood, in your case, you add a new method outside the class, I would like to do this inside the constructor if it's possible.

Comment: @J.BizMai That's not hard either, use the same mechanism: https://3v4l.org/DmjUT If you don't want it available except through boolean switch maybe? Or something, add that as a check for the constructor.